# Populate multiple cells based on selection from data in other sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, database

I have this data regarding postal products with prices based on weight range.

[image: data]

I want to be able in another sheet to insert a postal product from a dropdown, e.g. "PS" then specify a weight in the adjacent cell, e.g. 51 grams so that excel automatically fills the price for that product in a third cell based on the the price for the weight range in the data ("fascia gr min - fascia gr max). Ideas ?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+import+data+from+a+SQL+database

Comment: What tool is the database in? SQL? MySQL? MongoDB? Firebird? Interbase? InnoDB?

Comment: @spikey_richie at the moment is just a sheet on excel.

Comment: Your question title mentions DB. A sheet in Excel is not a database. So you want to take certain data from one sheet/workbook, and display it in another sheet/workbook?

Comment: @spikey_richie yep. When adding data in excel you get the option to select it from a DB, a csv, an excel file. It’s very little data so I don’t want to setup a real DB

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: OK, so like the bot says, it's not clear what you're actually asking for help with, and it's not clear what you've done so far. Please update your questions with some specifics about your set up, and expected outcomes, and why you can't get to where you want to be.

Comment: @spikey_richie edited

Comment: Doing drop downs and lookups in excel are really well documented online, so what research have you done and what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

1] Add a new line in Row 20 with Product name "AR" in `B20` , so that each product will have minium 3 lines.

2] Criteria put in Column G and H

3] In "Result Rate" `I2`, formula copied down :

```
=LOOKUP(H2,OFFSET($B$1,MATCH(G2,$B:$B,0)-1,1,COUNTIF(B:B,G2),3))
```

[image]

Comment: Excel tells me the formula contains an error

Comment: Post the formula, to check how do you used the formula.

Comment: it had to be translated

Comment: How do I transform this formula if I want to move the data to a "data" sheet and keep the part you put from G in another sheet starting from A

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using `FILTER()` to extract a subset of your table matching the product ("PS" for example) and perform an `XLOOKUP()` on it to find your desired result.

Say your table is in A1:E19 (headers in row 1), your product is entered in cell G2, and your weight is entered in cell G3.

The `XLOOKUP()` will take the value in G3 (weight) and seek it in column C's data (fascia gr min). It will take the index value that returns it and find the matching data in column E's data (imponibile). However, it cannot use the main data table directly as there are several "PS" items and it will only return the first match.

You COULD use "OG" techniques to use multiple values as a single lookup so that it would work, but there is no need nowadays and those worked best with exact matches anyway. Which this is not.

So you use `FILTER()` to build a virtual table inside the formula which only has "PS" items. Since it will have only "PS" items, you won't be looking up the "PS" value in them as they are all "PS" related values. What you will look up will be unique in the virtual table, the weight. So `XLOOKUP()` can help you nicely:

```
=XLOOKUP($G$3,FILTER(C2:C19,B2:B19=$G$2),FILTER(E2:E19,B2:B19=$G$2),,-1)
```

(Believe it or not, you do not actually need to sort your data table as `XLOOKUP()` will effectively (not really, but the end result is exactly as if it had) sort it internally when it uses the data `FILTER()` subsets for it.)

`FILTER()` appears twice as it first provides the column for matching the lookup value to get its index (relative up/down position in this case) then second provides the column to use that to get a result value. The value in G2 limits the rows selected to just the product (PS in this case).

It might seem like you could use it once and just specify the whole E2:E19 range for the results, but that will fail. It has to match the lookup column in size. So you need both `FILTER()`'s.

Otherwise it is a completely straightforward `XLOOKUP()`. You give it a value to look up in cell G3, the lookup range and result columns to lookup and get a result from, and one final detail:  you want to find the value being sought, or, if there is no exact match (as normally there would not be one), then the next smaller value actually present. So do the search you mention, just for 62 perhaps and it fails to find the 62, and looks for the next smaller value actually present, finding 51 and returning 3.11 euros. That is done with the fifth parameter, the last one used in the formula:  the "-1" at the end.

You could get slicker ("more complicated") and test the weight value to see if it exceeds the highest weight listed in column D for any given product. Could be important if that meant the item had to be priced completely differently, or perhaps would therefore be a different product, or whatever else might apply. (Perhaps take the highest value for the product as a base and add more according to some cost for the extra weight. So many possibilities.)

Last thought is that this will work for products that have any number of rows greater than 0 be it 1 or 100.

*(The absolute key to it all is making sure you present `XLOOKUP()` two virtual columns of the same size. Any time you do something like this and it fails, having forgotten to do that is the most likely cause of the failure.)*